# JavaScript CAML Query- Alter Column Name

Tags: javascript, caml

Is there any way to control what name a column is returned as when a CAML query is run?  I am interested in passing the results of several queries (on related items) to a single function, and as the lists were not originally planned for this, they were not created using a content type or standardized column names.  I was hoping for something along the lines of `context.load(collListItems, 'Include(Event_x0020_Start_x0020_Date as startDate)');`.  Is there any chance that something like this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Process all the results into a single javascript array of objects - that way you can decide what fields go where in the objects.